# insert a varios id con varios rows?

Tags: mysql

tengo una lista de 200 id del siguiente formato

```
  2882000084387468/2
  2882000011383248/2
  2882000012311388/2
  2882000011133188/2
  2882000014431388/2
  2882000787011388/2
```

y tengo que hacer un insert con un formato parecido a este para cada uno de esos id

```
INSERT INTO GrupoP  (gp, p, principal, cxc, em, dec, servicio, persona_id, fecha, status) 
VALUES ('2050', (SELECT p.p_id FROM Pol p WHERE lsid= '2882000011388/2'), '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', NOW(), '1'),
('2176', (SELECT p.p_id FROM Pol p WHERE lsid= '2882000011388/2'), '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', NOW(), '1'),
('2189', (SELECT p.p_id FROM Pol  p WHERE lsid= '2882000011388/2'), '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', NOW(), '1'),
('2160', (SELECT p.p_id FROM Pol  p WHERE lsid= '2882000011388/2'), '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', NOW(), '1');
```

Como puedo hacer sin ir haciendo uno por uno con cada id

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Dónde tienes esos valores que mencionas? ¿Qué has intentado al respecto? ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes en el código? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: los valores son una simple lista que me pasaron en un txt, y debo hacerlo en mysql, debo hacer un script con el que pueda hacer el insert de cada id pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: Ya, pero sin explicar por ejemplo cómo recibes ese archivo, mediante qué programa, etc, poco podremos decirte. O, si ese archivo está en una ubicación en específico de tu servidor, qué lenguaje de servidor usas, si debe ser procesado desde mysql o desde el lenguaje de servidor ... es decir, faltan detalles importantes del contexto que no son explicados en tu pregunta.

Comment: no, solo es en mysql y solo es una lista de todos los id tal cual es un txt

Comment: En ese caso puedes usar `LOAD DATA IN FILE`, revisa [este tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/) donde se explica cómo funciona. Luego prueba y si tienes algún error nos dices.